# Why would this. return undefine?

Tags: javascript, oop

I wonder why this.show would return undefined, meanwhilte quiz.show will return the function.

This code works:

```
const quiz = {
//Generates the quiz
generateQuiz: () => {
    quiz.resetQ();
    quiz.generateRandomQuestions();
    quiz.displayQuiz();
    quiz.show();
},
```

This returns undefined:

```
const quiz = {
//Generates the quiz
generateQuiz: () => {
    this.resetQ();
    this.generateRandomQuestions();
    this.displayQuiz();
    this.show();
},
```

Comment: Don't abuse arrow function, if you don't understand how it works. Use `generateQuiz: function () {`

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using classes?

Comment: Not experienced enough to use classes! Trying to understand arrow functions

Comment: Have a read of this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes 

Comment: please share more info I mean functions you have mentioned